# Translate transition with String in JavaFX

Tags: text, javafx, translate

I would like move vertically with the String which is converted to Text and then implemented 
into translate transition. When I start it, nothing happened. Any idea how could it work.
Thanks.

Code:

> public class Pohyb extends Application {
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
>
>     Group root = new Group();
>     Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
>     scene.setFill(Paint.valueOf("B0B0B0"));
>     primaryStage.setTitle("Canvas");
>
>
>     primaryStage.setScene(scene);
>     startTransition(scene);
>     primaryStage.show();   
>
>
> }
>
> /**
>  * @param args the command line arguments
>  */
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     launch(args);
> }
>
> private void startTransition(Scene scene) {
>
>
>     //OBDELNÍK
>      final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(32, 32);
>      rect.setLayoutX((300/2)- (32/2));
>      rect.setLayoutY((300/2)- (32/2));
>      rect.setFill(Paint.valueOf("ffffff"));
>
>      Text text = new Text("A");
>      text.setLayoutX(145);
>      text.setLayoutY(155);
>
>
>      Group root = (Group) scene.getRoot();
>      root.getChildren().add(rect);
>      root.getChildren().add(text);
>
>       final TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition(new Duration(1000));
>         translate.setNode(text);
>         translate.setFromY(text.getLayoutY());
>         translate.setToX(text.getLayoutY() + 100);
>         translate.setAutoReverse(true);
>         translate.setCycleCount(5);
>         translate.play();
> }    }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you increase the size of the stage you'll see your animation working, but at a higher Y coordinate than expected.

If you look at the javadoc for `TranslateTransition`, it states that it will use `translateY` property by default. So this will work:

```
final TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition(new Duration(1000));
translate.setNode(text);
translate.setFromY(text.getTranslateY());
translate.setToY(text.getTranslateY()+100);
translate.setAutoReverse(true);
translate.setCycleCount(5);
translate.play();
```

This will also work, since the `byY` property will by used if no `toY` one is provided:

```
final TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition(new Duration(1000));
translate.setNode(text);
translate.setByY(100);
translate.setAutoReverse(true);
translate.setCycleCount(5);
translate.play();
```

Comment: Thanks much. I did not realize the posibilities of "translate". Now it works.